# Posting back json data

Tags: php, arrays, json, post

I am trying to send back some json data to the server but nothing worked so far D:

The first thing I do is to get the data by executing this:

```
$oldData = file_get_contents('dataset/dataset.json');
$oldData = json_decode($oldData, true);
$oldBlock = $oldData['data'][0]['blocks'];
```

Now I change some values and want to send the changed stuff back but I do not know how to do that. What I know is that I have to encode the array again.

Thank you

Comment: If the `back` you're referring to is the client, consider using AJAX, prefferably using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: No, I do not want to send the data back to the client but to the server and change the file "dataset/dataset.json" from where I got the data at first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL in php:

```
$url = ""; // whatever url
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$newBlock = json_encode(...); // your new json to send

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($newBlock));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This should do the trick.